# Why would Meteor.Accounts return "has no method 'onCreateUser'"?

Tags: meteor, account

I'm trying to add an accountActive and accountExpirationDate to a user's profile when it is created. According to everything I've read, I should use Accounts.onCreateUser like so:

```
// Add accountActive and accountExpirationDate
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
  if (options.profile) {
    user.profile = options.profile;
    user.profile.accountActive          =   false;
    user.profile.accountExpirationDate  =   null;
  }
  return user;
});
```

The two fields are not being added and I'm receiving this error in Console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'onCreateUser'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it running on the client?  That function is only on the server.

Comment: You can ensure code loads only on the server by putting that code in a file within the `./server` sub-directory of your project.

Comment: @user728291 Make that an answer. That solved it. I was using a config.js in the client folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the Accounts.onCreateUser was running in the client folder. It cannot operate in the client, only on the server.

Comment: I had accidentally used it in the lib folder where it works but still throws an error (because lib is both client and server, obvs) - moved it to server folder and hey presto.